# How to use Python to run commands after first command has changed the session

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I'm using Python to run local shell command, with "subprocess":

```
subprocess.call("docker exec -it transcoder /bin/bash", shell=True, stdout=output, stderr=output)
subprocess.call("ffmpeg", shell=True, stdout=output, stderr=output)
```

The two command above which run step by step manually will like :

```
#first command  executed
#docker exec -it transcoder /bin/bash  output as :
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
root@85fe13a:/#
```

Those I describe it as it has changed the session context, so that the next command run within the new context, manual run next command, like:

```
#2nd command  executed
root@85fe13a:/# ffmpeg
ffmpeg version n4.3-dev-3911-g00afeaf548 Copyright .....
```

---

Okay, let's run in Python:

```
s = """
docker exec -it transcoder /bin/bash
ffmpeg
"""

subprocess.run([s], shell=True)
```

The output will be like:

```
#docker exec -it transcoder /bin/bash  output as :
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
root@85fe13a:/#
```

The command 'ffmpeg' seems not to work!

I want run new command continually after first command done. Since I have test the command as below which runs well as expected:

```
s = """
cd /www/pathDir
ls

"""

subprocess.run([s], shell=True)
```

but now my case not work, what's difference between these two cases and can subprocess or Python will work in any pattern as I expected?

---

After days of environment's fix and fix, then the Docker library in Python installed correctly; we use it to run commands as follows:

```
import docker                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')                                                                                                                                                                                                         
c = client.containers.run('image', detach=True, tty = True,  volumes = {                                                                                                                                                                        
     '/www' : {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
         'bind' : '/www',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
         'mode' : 'rw'                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 }

print(c.logs(), c.exec_run( "ffmpeg -i /www/xxx.MP4" ))
```

But another way like: `docker exec -it transcoder ffmpeg`  also works well.

[python docker lib Can't open an interactive container](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/390)

Thanks @David Maze !

That's all from a Docker beginner.

Comment: You are *not* running `docker` and `ffmpeg` sequentially in the same, local shell, rather the `ffmpeg` command is run in the interactive shell you get from `docker -it /bin/bash`. You could run `ffmpeg` directly instead of `bash`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `docker exec` in routine work.  (It brings all of the complications and permission issues around using Docker, plus it's not the "normal" path to run a container so you won't be able to see things like the process output.)  Can you install `ffmpeg` locally and just use `subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', ...])`?  (There are serious security problems around `shell=True`, avoid it if at all possible.)

Comment: Or, if you do have Docker, and you have the unrestricted root-level permissions required to use it, consider using the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/) to create a temporary container that runs the image with `ffmpeg` in it.

Comment: thanks . I've tried Docker Library in python，but from_env() issued error, so I try this..

Comment: maybe my case is relation to the question [docker-interactive-mode-and-executing-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101596/docker-interactive-mode-and-executing-script), i'm not sure, I'll have a test ---- Then , result : not according to mine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write to a Python subprocess' stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin) (Note that this answers the Y problem, see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) for the X Problem see: [Starting docker container using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433576/starting-docker-container-using-python-script)